# Share a quote to Twitter

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make an anime quote generator. Currently making a button that should share the quote from the generator to Twitter. However when pressing the button it doesn't share the qoute to Twitter.

Help appreciated how to solve it.

```js
const api = "https://animechan.vercel.app/api/random";
const anime = document.getElementById("anime");
const quote = document.getElementById("quote");
const character = document.getElementById("character");
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
document.getElementById("twitter")
btn.addEventListener("click", getQuote);
twitter.addEventListener("click", tweetQuote);


function getQuote() {
  fetch(api)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      anime.innerHTML = `"${data.anime}"`;
      quote.innerHTML = `"${data.quote}"`;
      character.innerHTML = `- ${data.character}`;
      btn.classList.remove("loading");
      btn.innerText = "New Quote";
    });
}
function tweetQuote() {
  window.open("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text="+$('data.quote')).text();
}
```

```html
<title>Anime Quote Generator </title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="quote-box">

      <h2 id="anime">Anime</h2>
      <br>
      <p id="quote">"Quote goes here..."</p>
      <small id="character">- Character</small>
    </div>
    <button id="btn">New Quote</button> 
    
    <br>
    <button id="twitter">TWEET</button> 
  </div>

    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "**can't get it to work**" is a totally unclear description. What does not work? What happens instead? Always give as much detail as possible. Having said that, it looks like you have a closing bracket in the wrong place, try `+$('data.quote').text());`

Answer (score 1):

I see three issues:

- A misplaced closing bracket, it should go after `.text()` instead of before it.
- An incorrect jQuery selector, it should be `$('#quote')` instead of `$('data.quote')`. The `data` object only exists inside the `fetch...then` handler function, also jQuery is built to look for DOM objects, it does not look for or use variables in your code.
- URL parameters need to be URL-encoded, or else the recipient may receive incomplete data and/or garbage data.

Improved code:

```js
function tweetQuote() {
  window.open("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + encodeURIComponent($('#quote').text()));
}
```

---

You can try it in the below code snippet (except I used `console.log` because `window.open` does not work in a snippet, you can copy the URL to a new browser window and then it should work).

```js
const api = "https://animechan.vercel.app/api/random";
const anime = document.getElementById("anime");
const quote = document.getElementById("quote");
const character = document.getElementById("character");
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");

document.getElementById("twitter")
btn.addEventListener("click", getQuote);
twitter.addEventListener("click", tweetQuote);

function getQuote() {
  fetch(api)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      anime.innerHTML = `"${data.anime}"`;
      quote.innerHTML = `"${data.quote}"`;
      character.innerHTML = `- ${data.character}`;
      btn.classList.remove("loading");
      btn.innerText = "New Quote";
    });
}

function tweetQuote() {
  console.log("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + encodeURIComponent($('#quote').text()));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Anime Quote Generator </title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="quote-box">

      <h2 id="anime">Anime</h2>
      <br>
      <p id="quote">"Quote goes here..."</p>
      <small id="character">- Character</small>
    </div>
    <button id="btn">New Quote</button> 
    
    <br>
    <button id="twitter">TWEET</button> 
  </div>

    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```